# MySQL 1052 Column 'userid' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not experienced in DB query, but I'm trying to get this data from MySQL:

```
$query->select(array($db->quoteName('userid')));
$query->select(' DATEDIFF(expires, now()) as dayleft');
$query->from($db->quoteName('product_order_status'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('userid') . ' LIKE '. $userID);
$query->where($db->quoteName('active') . ' LIKE '. '1');
$query->from($db->quoteName('product_orders'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('processor') . ' LIKE '. 'paypal');
```

What I'm trying to get is-

1. From **product_order_status** table

   - Get date range - ***Working***
   - Get orders with 'active' field value '1' for current user - ***Working***
2. From **product_orders** table

   - Get payment process from 'process' field where value is 'paypal'. - When I add this query it's not working and showing error: **1052 Column 'userid' in field list is ambiguous**

How can I make this query properly so I can get Active Orders which processed by PayPal for current logged in user?

Comment: This error means that multiple tables are being used in the query but the column you are asking for exists in more than 1 table. So you need to specify which table like so: `SELECT sample1.userid FROM sample1 LEFT JOIN sample2 ON sample1.id = sample2.id`

Comment: Can you write full code based on above queries please? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the PHP Library you are using to generate these queries, but your answer may look something like this:

```
$query->select(array($db->quoteName('product_order_status.userid')));
$query->select(' DATEDIFF(expires, now()) as dayleft');
$query->from($db->quoteName('product_order_status'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('product_order_status.userid') . ' LIKE "'. $userID . '"');
$query->where($db->quoteName('active') . ' LIKE '. '1');
$query->from($db->quoteName('product_orders'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('processor') . ' LIKE '. '"paypal"');
```

Or possibly this:

```
$query->select(array('`product_order_status`.`userid`'));
$query->select(' DATEDIFF(expires, now()) as dayleft');
$query->from($db->quoteName('product_order_status'));
$query->where('`product_order_status`.`userid`' . ' LIKE "'. $userID . '"');
$query->where($db->quoteName('active') . ' LIKE '. '1');
$query->from($db->quoteName('product_orders'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('processor') . ' LIKE '. '"paypal"');
```

Comment: The second one assumes that `$db->quoteName()` is only there to add the backtick character (`\``) to each side of the string you give it.

Comment: @sifur Did this answer your question?

Comment: I'm using PHP 7, it's showing this error now- `1054 Unknown column 'paypal' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Your string `"paypal"` was not escaped so MySQL thought it was a table name. I have updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: Awesome, which one of the code blocks worked for you? (So future googler's are not confused)